# Mysql & PHP search table for records whose value is between two dates and other record values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table similar to this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
id  | project_id  | dateValue    | textValue     | key
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 1           | 2018-10-25   | NULL          | closing_date
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2   | 2           | 2018-10-26   | NULL          | listing_date
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
3   | 3           | 2018-10-27   | NULL          | closing_date
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
4   | 1           | NULL         | Pending       | contract_status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
5   | 2           | NULL         | Active        | contract_status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
6   | 3           | NULL         | Pending acc.  | contract_status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I cannot get this to return any results.. Any suggestions? I need it to return project_ids "1 & 3"

```
 SELECT     t.*
 FROM       Table t
 WHERE      ((t.dateValue BETWEEN '2018-10-24' AND '2018-10-27') AND        (t.key = 'contract_status' AND t.textValue IN ('Pending','Pending acc.'))
 GROUP BY   t.project_id
```

I've tried this variation as well:

```
 SELECT     t.*
 FROM       Table t
 WHERE      ((t.dateValue BETWEEN '2018-10-24' AND '2018-10-27') AND        (t.key IN ('contract_status', 'closing_date') AND t.textValue IN ('Pending','Pending acc.'))
 GROUP BY   t.project_id
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your criteria doesn't match. 1-3 don't have the key and 4-6 don't have the date. Maybe your application is inserting data instead of updating the records?

Comment: With you data sample, both queries will not return anything. Check again your conditions.

Comment: When you use GROUP BY, on the SELECT clause you can only use columns explicitly declared on the GROUP BY clause or aggregations methods over the rest of the columns. Just a tip.

Comment: @LargeTuna please check the posted answer and let know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Thanks, trying to work it into my existing code base...

Answer (score 0):

Your DB schema is weird and goal is not clear.

Here is something you can use to understand why you are not getting any result:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/701a65/3

```
SELECT     t.project_id,
MAX(t.dateValue),
MAX(t.textValue)
 FROM      t
 WHERE (t.dateValue BETWEEN '2018-10-24' AND '2018-10-27'
 AND   (t.key = 'closing_date'))
 OR t.textValue IN ('Pending','Pending acc.')
 GROUP BY   t.project_id
```

But you should definitely redesign your DB and read more about relational databases.

Your main problem is your `WHERE` clause.

```
WHERE ((t.dateValue BETWEEN '2018-10-24' AND '2018-10-27') 
   AND (t.key = 'contract_status' 
   AND t.textValue IN ('Pending','Pending acc.'))
```

You use `AND` everywhere that means you want to find all records which has for example `dateValue` AND `textValue` - but in your raw data there is no such records at all. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Since your dataset does not cover all the conditions in one single row. You may use conditional aggregation with `Having` clause:

```
SELECT t.project_id, 
       SUM(IF(t.dateValue BETWEEN '2018-10-24' 
                              AND '2018-10-27', 
              1, 0)) AS date_check, 
       SUM(IF(t.key = 'contract_status' AND 
              t.textValue IN ('Pending','Pending acc.'), 
              1, 0)) AS key_check   
FROM Table t
GROUP BY t.project_id 
HAVING date_check > 0 AND 
       key_check > 0
```

Comment: You are only adding complexity when there is no need to do.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte OP's dataset is more like a log entry. For different activities, there are different rows, and they keep on getting updated individually. A simple Where condition will not suffice

Comment: I am going to have to rethink my schema, this query is way to slow to pull back results - over 3 seconds.

Comment: @LargeTuna yes it will be slow because of conditional aggregation. But based on your current schema, it seems to be correct solution.

Comment: It does work, thanks! Just too slow because how I built my schema :(